# Boostrap 4 hamburger icon is gone after customizing

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, navbar

I was trying to customize boostrap 4 navbar and I copied navbar code from the boostrap website and removed class navbar-light and bg-light and replaced when with class navbar-custom. I managed changing the color of the navbar, but I realized that the hamburger icon is gone when I make the site smaller and the icon is not showing anymore. I also checked the data-target has the correct id as the ul id. but why the icon is gone once I removed class navbar-light and bg-light.

Please have a look at my code [here](https://codepen.io/kingsfull123/pen/VXddOb?editors=1100)

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes specifically from your removal of `navbar-light`.

Bootstrap 4 styles the dropdown toggle based on this class (in `_navbar.scss`):

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

You can either add these styles to your custom class:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Or better yet, simply *keep* the default `navbar-light` class, and instead apply your custom styles to the `navbar` / `navbar-toggle` / `navbar-collapse` trio of classes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I can see that the icon was affected once the navbar-light has been removed. So maybe I just leave it as it is and add a new class "navbar-custom" to it and style it in css to give it a custom look. I hope it does not look too amature.